как запустить два модуля одновременно из основного файла main.py?
Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно запустить два модуля одновременно?
Импортирую в main.py из папки setting_websocket два web-сокета. По отдельности, при запуске вручную оба запускаются и работают нормально, в отдельных окнах, но вместе не запускаются.
Пробовал разные конструкции не помогло. Импорт запускает только первый модуль данных. Второй не запускается - или запускается только в ручном режиме.
Не хочется писать "костыль" в виде cmd-файла.
По поводу многопоточности прошу не заморачиваться. Я не пытаюсь распараллелить проект на ядра процессоров или потоки - там нет такой нагрузки. Просто два потока данных с разных серверов летят, поэтому каждый сокет реализован в отдельном файле.
Спасибо.
import importlib
from setting_websocket import WebSocket1, WebSocket2

run(WebSocket1, WebSocket2) # не работает
reload.importlib(WebSocket1, WebSocket2) # не работает

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


Используйте функции/классы для объявления сокетов в WebSocket1 и WebSocket2 чтобы при импорте  они автоматически не запускались. После используйте threading.

threading - не используется вообще. Модули WebSocket1, WebSocket2 должны одновременно запуститься при старте mai.py. WebSocket1, WebSocket2 работают автономно. Их просто нужно запустить.

asyncio не получится использовать, пока сокеты не асинхронные поэтому можно использовать threading. Я имел ввиду начать его использовать.

Оба модуля WebSocket1, WebSocket2 в себя сами импортируют asyncio.

При импорте python запускает код находящийся в модуле в случае если в коде модуля находится длинный по времени код то он не продолжит исполнение основной программы, пока тот не будет выполнен. Поэтому перенесите весь код в модуле в функцию, после импортируйте её и запустите используя либо asyncio, либо threading, либо что-либо другое позволяющее запустить их в параллели.

А ларчик открывался просто...

# запуск websocket-потока module1
# запуск websocket-потока module2

import asyncio  
from setting_websocket.WebSocketModule1 import module1  
from setting_websocket.WebSocketModule2 import module2 
  
async def main():  

# Запускаем обе функции параллельно  
    await asyncio.gather(  
        module1(),  
        module2()  
    )  
  
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    asyncio.run(main())

Естественно, в модулях необходимо закомментировать строчку:
# asyncio.run(module1())
# строчку нужно раскомментировать если нужно отдельно запустить данный модуль. Например для проверки связи с сервером.

Осталось найти, как вывести в разные окна два потока данных...
